# Arrayformula not copying down when using AverageIF

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Having trouble making `ARRAYFORMULA` copy down its values when using it in combination with `AVERAGEIF`.  Here is my google [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UNpJk9TY6BEXakGIFyi8YPOlmXvj9hY63uu31TCEbVA/edit?usp=sharing). It works fine when I copy down the formula, it just won't auto-populate.

Here is my current formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGEIF(A2:A,A2,B2:B))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY(A2:B, 
 "select A,avg(B) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  label avg(B)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]